# Is there a way to remap key values for an object iterated using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, soundmanager2

I am using angularjs-soundmanager2 and the object array must conform to this object

```
{id: n, title: 'Title', artist: 'Artist', url: 'URL'}
```

I am accessing a remote API that gives me this object

```
{id: n, filename: 'URL', title: 'Title'}
```

What I want to do is remap the latter object to conform to the former. I tried using a filter within ng-repeat, but that doesn't seem to produce a result without getting iteration abort (angular gives me this error `[$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`).

```
app.filter('mapAudio', function() {
    return function(items, field) {
        var filtered = [];

        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            filtered.push({id: item.id, title: item.title, artist: '', url: item.filename});
        });

        return filtered;
    };
});
```

On the HTML side:

```
<a ng-repeat="sample in selected.audio | mapAudio" href="#" class="list-group-item">{{sample.title}}</a>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have to do it in the ng-repeat? Could this be done in the service that calls the remote api at the time the response comes back? It seems likely that, if you need the data in this specific format, you would need it everywhere in that format. It would be cleaner if you did that transformation once. Then, none of your view controllers need to be aware that the format was something other than the soundmanager2 format.

Comment: @mcgraphix I wish I could do it in the remote service, but unfortunately I have no control over the response format. You're right, that would make complete sense to do it that way, but I have no say over that part of the data.

Comment: I didnt mean on the server. I meant in your service in your angular app. Normally, you wouldnt make ajax requests right in your controller. Instead you would use a service (look up angular.service()) so it is still in your control to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you update the source list?

```
<a ng-repeat="sample in getFullModels(selected.audio) | mapAudio" href="#" class="list-group-item">{{sample.title}}</a>
```

`#getFullModels` would have to code to return full model representation.

Comment: is getFullModels() part of the controller scope (i.e. $scope)?